# Radio button Selection after submitting form in jsp/servlet

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets

i am submitting form with radio button. and i want that radio button as checked after submitting a form. basically i am doing some searching process on page. please check code.

on my jsp.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <% 
                String buttonvalue = (String) request.getParameter("radio");
        %>
        <%= buttonvalue %>

        <form method="post" action="SearchServlet">

            <script type='text/javascript'>
            var button = "<%= buttonvalue %>";
            if(button == "one")
            {
                alert("1");
                document.getElementById("rdone").checked = true;
                document.getElementById("rdtwo").checked = false;
                document.getElementById("rdthree").checked = false;
            }
            else if(button == "two")
            {
                document.getElementById("rdone").checked = false;
                document.getElementById("rdtwo").checked = true;
                document.getElementById("rdthree").checked = false;   
            }
            else if(button == "three")
            {
                alert("3");
                document.getElementById("rdone").checked = false;
                document.getElementById("rdtwo").checked = false;
                document.getElementById("rdthree").checked = true;
                alert("2");
            }
            else
            {
                    alert("4");
            }
        </script>

            <input id="rdone" type="radio" name="radio" value="one"/>
            <input id="rdtwo" type="radio" name="radio" value="two"/>
            <input id="rdthree" type="radio" name="radio" value="three"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

and in Servlet.

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try 
        {
            System.out.println(request.getParameter("radio"));
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/radiobutton.jsp");
            System.out.println("--------------"+request.getParameter("radio"));
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        } 
        finally 
        {            
            out.close();
        }

    }
```

all working fine. but i am getting java script error. please check following screen shot. because of this java script i am not getting exact output.

[image]

Comment: **Danger**: You are outputting data from the URL directly into the page. This renders you vulnerable to [XSS attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script appears before the radio buttons, and doesn't consist of a function that gets delayed until later.

You are trying to modify the buttons before they exist.

Move the script to after the buttons in the HTML source.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you that when your JSP page is submit you can handle it on servlet using following code:

```
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
        {
            response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            try 
            {
                System.out.println(request.getParameter("radio"));
if(request.getParameter("radio")!= "" || request.getParameter("radio")!=null){
 request.setAttribute("radio");
}
                RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/radiobutton.jsp");
                System.out.println("--------------"+request.getParameter("radio"));
                dispatcher.forward(request, response);
            } 
            finally 
            {            
                out.close();
            }

        }
```

now add following line in your JSP file:

```
<input id="rdone" type="radio" name="radio" value="one" <%=((request.getAttribute("radio")!=null && request.getAttribute("radio").toString().equals("one")) ? "checked" : "")%> />
<input id="rdtwo" type="radio" name="radio" value="two" <%=((request.getAttribute("radio")!=null && request.getAttribute("radio").toString().equals("two")) ? "checked" : "")%> />
<input id="rdthree" type="radio" name="radio" value="three" <%=((request.getAttribute("radio")!=null && request.getAttribute("radio").toString().equals("three")) ? "checked" : "")%> />
```